# How can agent J be a member of MIB when K was killed by Boris

Tags: men-in-black-3, men-in-black

In **Men In Black**, Agent K recruits Agent J. However, in **Men In Black 3**, K was killed by Boris in the past, and next morning, J was still a part of MIB.

How can it be possible? K recruited J and K was killed (obviously before he recruited J).

Am I missing here something?

Comment: Bearing in mind that they were **still writing the film** when they started filming, the better answer is "what the hell were they thinking, not having a completed script before starting filming?".

Comment: It doesn't seem too unlikely that another MIB agent would have seen the same kind of skills in Jay that Kay did. He "*ran down a Cephalopod. On foot"* then scored very highly in the MIB tests.

Comment: Obviously J was K and they were both each other's grandfathers.

Comment: Well, if killing K in the past caused everything K did to be undone, the Earth would have been destroyed in the first movie. Obviously, in this universe time tries to mitigate damage.

Comment: I'm going to assume the presence of wibbly-wobbly timey-whimey...stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The movie explicitly states that J is in a time paradox, as evidenced by his craving for chocolate milk, which O says is a indication of time fracture..

So as a paradox, it's obviously not in a stable state.

It should be noted that the alien Griffin is frequently observing "This must be the one where somethingsomethingsomething", obviously implying that other time tracks co-exist.   In a time fracture, leaks from one timeline to another should not be impossible.  I also seem to recall that the chocolate milk may even give one a measure of immunity.

Answer (score -4):

> Am I missing here something?

Yes you are. You are taking it for granted that changing an event in the past would create ripples which **will** change whatever had happened after the point-of-contact.

I mean, its not a proven fact that changing a past event will lead to a completely different future.

Also, how can you be sure that in MI4 or something, some guy kills Boris even before Boris has a chance to kill K?

My point is, it's fiction and thus anything is possible.

Comment: Changing the past will obviously affect the future! If it does not, then why would killing J in the past will make J to be dead in the future?

Comment: @SiddharthVenu they mean perhaps a different agent ended up recruiting J.

Comment: @SiddharthVenu I never said changing the past won't affect the future. I'm just saying that it will not affect each and every bit of the future, as if time has recorded the previous future somewhere, compares it and then gives out a completely different future in every aspect, just because a particular incident happened in a different way.